# No JavaScript Multiple Popups?

Tags: html, css, popup, gallery

Using the method described [here: http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/pure-css-popup-without-javascript](http://www.sevensignature.com/blog/code/pure-css-popup-without-javascript)

i have been able to replicate this method on my own working site. However, the problem i am facing happens when i add additional links.

i have a page/image gallery of thumbnails. When i click on a  thumbnail, i would like it to have its own popup. The above technique seems to only work when you have just one link/popup

Can i edit it so that it will accommodate multiple popups?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite possible with example you provided
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXXdEm
working fine on chromium v42

href field of <a>  and id field of div with class overlay whould be the same

```
<div class="box">
    <a class="button" href="#popup___2">Another pop up</a>
</div>

<div id="popup___2" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <h2>I am another</h2>
        <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
        <div class="content">
            other content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```